# How to preprocess all datasets from folder through a script in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have folder with many files

```
C:/1/vyd
```

Names of these files

```
/new_vydel_1
/new_vydel_2
/new_vydel_n...
/new_vydel_725
```

short dput of 2 such datasets

```
new_vydel_1=structure(list(date = c("08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018"), row = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), col = c(49L, 50L, 51L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L), B1 = c(6914L, 6914L, 6914L, 6958L, 6958L, 6958L, 6958L, 
6914L, 6914L, 6914L), B2 = c(5560L, 5380L, 5644L, 5088L, 5280L, 
5200L, 5472L, 5568L, 5560L, 5424L), B3 = c(4768L, 4840L, 4936L, 
4320L, 4388L, 4572L, 4640L, 4704L, 4696L, 4488L), B4 = c(4960L, 
4964L, 4540L, 4164L, 4412L, 4608L, 4628L, 4588L, 4416L, 4312L
), B5 = c(5554L, 5554L, 4782L, 4736L, 4736L, 5018L, 5018L, 4968L, 
4968L, 4677L), B6 = c(5249L, 5249L, 4428L, 4553L, 4553L, 4832L, 
4832L, 4741L, 4741L, 4428L), B7 = c(4893L, 4893L, 4138L, 4527L, 
4527L, 4681L, 4681L, 4505L, 4505L, 4170L), B8 = c(4836L, 4840L, 
5044L, 4074L, 4236L, 4404L, 4592L, 4668L, 4796L, 4628L), B8A = c(4679L, 
4679L, 4098L, 4524L, 4524L, 4643L, 4643L, 4460L, 4460L, 3987L
), B9 = c(6752L, 6752L, 6752L, 7098L, 7098L, 7098L, 7098L, 6752L, 
6752L, 6752L), B10 = c(4170L, 4170L, 3407L, 3301L, 3301L, 3612L, 
3612L, 3600L, 3600L, 3352L), B11 = c(3124L, 3124L, 2514L, 2969L, 
2969L, 3137L, 3137L, 2922L, 2922L, 2487L), B12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), COCта = c("2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", 
"2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", 
"2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

and

```
new_vydel_2=structure(list(date = c("08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018"), row = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L), col = c(5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L), B1 = c(8136L, 8136L, 7369L, 8136L, 8136L, 7369L, 8136L, 
8136L, 8136L, 7369L), B2 = c(5796L, 5756L, 5912L, 5956L, 6000L, 
6196L, 6044L, 6164L, 6268L, 6588L), B3 = c(4840L, 4936L, 5096L, 
5040L, 5096L, 5292L, 5280L, 5360L, 5480L, 5584L), B4 = c(4868L, 
4996L, 4908L, 4932L, 5060L, 5136L, 5280L, 5444L, 5492L, 5500L
), B5 = c(5327L, 5327L, 5301L, 5471L, 5471L, 5301L, 5471L, 5471L, 
5846L, 5977L), B6 = c(5207L, 5207L, 5087L, 5290L, 5290L, 5087L, 
5290L, 5290L, 5777L, 5721L), B7 = c(5235L, 5235L, 5001L, 5241L, 
5241L, 5001L, 5241L, 5241L, 5688L, 5539L), B8 = c(4876L, 4828L, 
4936L, 4992L, 5052L, 5236L, 5236L, 5336L, 5380L, 5708L), B8A = c(5209L, 
5209L, 4889L, 5233L, 5233L, 4889L, 5233L, 5233L, 5787L, 5324L
), B9 = c(8407L, 8407L, 7048L, 8407L, 8407L, 7048L, 8407L, 8407L, 
8407L, 7048L), B10 = c(3343L, 3343L, 3188L, 3438L, 3438L, 3188L, 
3438L, 3438L, 3774L, 3543L), B11 = c(2740L, 2740L, 2443L, 2800L, 
2800L, 2443L, 2800L, 2800L, 3228L, 2669L), B12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), COCта = c("5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", 
"5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", 
"5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Each of these dataset i must preprocess through this script for example

```
treespring2=new_vydel_1 %>% 
  separate(COCта, into = c("B","E","C","OC","OLS"), sep=c(1,4,6,8), remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(C,B,E,OC,OLS), ~stringr::str_remove_all(., "[A-Z]"))) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(C,B,E,OC,OLS), ~as.numeric(.)*10))
str(treespring2)
```

But if I have 1000 datasets, then every time I have to manually change the dataset in this script. It's very long and cumbersome.
Is there a way to automatically take all these datasets and preprocess them one by one through  script, and then bind them through `rbind` into one dataframe, as in the example

Here  dput() example of final result.

```
final=structure(list(date = c("08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", "08.01.2018", 
"08.01.2018", "08.01.2018"), row = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L), col = c(49L, 
50L, 51L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L), B1 = c(6914L, 6914L, 6914L, 6958L, 6958L, 
6958L, 6958L, 6914L, 6914L, 6914L, 8136L, 8136L, 7369L, 8136L, 
8136L, 7369L, 8136L, 8136L, 8136L, 7369L), B2 = c(5560L, 5380L, 
5644L, 5088L, 5280L, 5200L, 5472L, 5568L, 5560L, 5424L, 5796L, 
5756L, 5912L, 5956L, 6000L, 6196L, 6044L, 6164L, 6268L, 6588L
), B3 = c(4768L, 4840L, 4936L, 4320L, 4388L, 4572L, 4640L, 4704L, 
4696L, 4488L, 4840L, 4936L, 5096L, 5040L, 5096L, 5292L, 5280L, 
5360L, 5480L, 5584L), B4 = c(4960L, 4964L, 4540L, 4164L, 4412L, 
4608L, 4628L, 4588L, 4416L, 4312L, 4868L, 4996L, 4908L, 4932L, 
5060L, 5136L, 5280L, 5444L, 5492L, 5500L), B5 = c(5554L, 5554L, 
4782L, 4736L, 4736L, 5018L, 5018L, 4968L, 4968L, 4677L, 5327L, 
5327L, 5301L, 5471L, 5471L, 5301L, 5471L, 5471L, 5846L, 5977L
), B6 = c(5249L, 5249L, 4428L, 4553L, 4553L, 4832L, 4832L, 4741L, 
4741L, 4428L, 5207L, 5207L, 5087L, 5290L, 5290L, 5087L, 5290L, 
5290L, 5777L, 5721L), B7 = c(4893L, 4893L, 4138L, 4527L, 4527L, 
4681L, 4681L, 4505L, 4505L, 4170L, 5235L, 5235L, 5001L, 5241L, 
5241L, 5001L, 5241L, 5241L, 5688L, 5539L), B8 = c(4836L, 4840L, 
5044L, 4074L, 4236L, 4404L, 4592L, 4668L, 4796L, 4628L, 4876L, 
4828L, 4936L, 4992L, 5052L, 5236L, 5236L, 5336L, 5380L, 5708L
), B8A = c(4679L, 4679L, 4098L, 4524L, 4524L, 4643L, 4643L, 4460L, 
4460L, 3987L, 5209L, 5209L, 4889L, 5233L, 5233L, 4889L, 5233L, 
5233L, 5787L, 5324L), B9 = c(6752L, 6752L, 6752L, 7098L, 7098L, 
7098L, 7098L, 6752L, 6752L, 6752L, 8407L, 8407L, 7048L, 8407L, 
8407L, 7048L, 8407L, 8407L, 8407L, 7048L), B10 = c(4170L, 4170L, 
3407L, 3301L, 3301L, 3612L, 3612L, 3600L, 3600L, 3352L, 3343L, 
3343L, 3188L, 3438L, 3438L, 3188L, 3438L, 3438L, 3774L, 3543L
), B11 = c(3124L, 3124L, 2514L, 2969L, 2969L, 3137L, 3137L, 2922L, 
2922L, 2487L, 2740L, 2740L, 2443L, 2800L, 2800L, 2443L, 2800L, 
2800L, 3228L, 2669L), B12 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), COCта = c("2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", 
"2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", 
"2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", 
"2B2OC2OLS3C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", 
"5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", "5OC3B1C1Е", 
"5OC3B1C1Е"), B = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L), Е = c(20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), C = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L), OC = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), OLS = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

all `NA` must be changed `0`

How can i perform this manipulations?
any help is valuable . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

I'm going to assume your files as .csv. Create list of those files (list_dfs), and then import the files to a list(my_data):

```
list_dfs<-list.files("C:/1/vyd",pattern="csv$",full.names = T)

my_data<-lapply(list_dfs,read.delim)
```

Now, regarding the preprocessing create a function with the necessary tasks (preprocess and replace NAs):

```
preprocess<-function(dat){
  treespring2=dat %>% 
    separate(COCта, into = c("B","E","C","OC","OLS"), sep=c(1,4,6,8), remove = F) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(C,B,E,OC,OLS), ~stringr::str_remove_all(., "[A-Z]"))) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(C,B,E,OC,OLS), ~as.numeric(.)*10))
  
  treespring2[is.na(treespring2)]<-0
  
  return(treespring2)
  }
```

With this function apply it to the list of dataframes(my_data):

```
dat.prep<-lapply(my_data, FUN=preprocess)
```

To finalize use do.call function to rbind a list of dataframes:

```
dat.bind<-do.call("rbind",dat.prep)
```

And you might get the desired output.